# How to read a java class/object name from property file and then initiate it?

Tags: java, spring

I have a class name/object in my property file, for example:

```
my.class.name = com.awesome.package.HelloWorld.
```

I want to read this class name from my property file, and then initiate it, so I can call the method in this class.

I have tried:

```
Class<?> classType = Class.forName(my.class.name);
```

But I cannot call the method of this class/object. Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you know what method you're calling?  You'll have to invoke it reflectively, with `classType.getMethod(...).invoke(...)`.

Comment: Here is more info and example of calling methods using reflection: 

https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-reflection

Comment: @LouisWasserman
Thanks for your info, but it does not work for me. I am using classType .newInstance(), then I can invoke the method